# Mavros, howto read second battery monitor

Tags: ros, mavlink

i am using both battery monitors on my pixhawk with Ardurover as fluid flow meters and need to get the data in my ROS ecosystem. After a fair amount of research, I was not able to find a reference to a second battery status besides the one published on
`mavros/battery` as `sensor_msgs/BatteryState`. But this seems to be for a single battery

Can someone please tell me that the second monitor is implemented and where to find it.....(please also tell me if this is not implemented yet)

Comment: Are there different values for the `location` or `serial_number` fields in that topic? Maybe both battery states get published on the same topic.

Comment: Unfortunately not. there is only

-string location          # The location into which the battery is inserted. (slot number or plug)

-string serial_number     # The best approximation of the battery serial number

Comment: I see. I think we have a misunderstanding. What I meant was: If you record the messages, are there different messages arriving with different values set in these attributes?